# qml LocalStorage query threaded

Tags: sqlite, qt, qml

Is it possible to run a localstorage database query in qml in a spererate thread?
My query on a big database takes 500ms which blocks the responsivenes of the ui.

My relevant code:

```
property var db: null
function openDB() {

    if(db !== null) return;

    db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("dbname", "0.1", "dbname", 3000000000);
}

function runQuery(query)
{
    var results
    db.readTransaction(function(tx) {
        results = tx.executeSql(query)
    });
    return results;
}
```

I want to run a query every second without blocking the ui.
e.g.

```
var osresult = runQuery('SELECT * FROM os_data')
```

where later I loop over the results to show them in a graph.
I looked at `WorkerScript` but with WorkerScript I have to use js files where I can not use  LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync.

How should one run queries in qml without blocking the UI?

Comment: I would place a query into [WorkerScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-workerscript.html).

Comment: @folibis as I described in my question I tried that, but how do you use LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync in a js script?

Comment: Ok, it looks that `LocalStorage` is not accessible inside `WorkerScript`, sorry. The only way to run some task without blocking the GUI is to run that in a separate thread. The `WorkerScript` is useless an so in this case I guess that the solution could be creating custom C++ item that accesses the Sqlite db and provide some functionality to QML.

Comment: C++ indeed seems to be the answer, see also: https://forum.qt.io/topic/44327/updating-local-storage-in-workerscript and https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-27454.